# What is the reason for the implication $2x \lt 2y \Rightarrow 2x + \sin x \lt 2y + \sin y$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functions, derivatives

I'm trying to prove that the function 
$$
f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}
$$
$$
x \rightarrow 2x + \sin x
$$

is strictly increasing and then injective.

So for $x,y \in \mathbb{R} \phantom{2} $ $x \lt y$ we have:

$$
x \lt y \Rightarrow 2x < 2y \Rightarrow 2x + \sin x \lt 2y + \sin y
$$

However we can see clearly that if 
$$
x < y \not \Rightarrow \sin x < \sin y
$$ 
but this fact does not seem to be relevant.
So, why is the reason that the fact of $f'(x)=2+\cos x>0$ is more relevant than $x < y \not \Rightarrow \sin x < \sin y$ ?

Please note that I'm not asking for a demonstration of this function to be injective, I know how to prove it with other simpler ways, I'm just interested on the reason of this last implication.

[image]

Comment: the derivative of $2x+\sin x$ is always positive, so that function is increasing

Comment: We have that $f'(x)=2+\cos(x)=1+\underbrace{(1+\cos(x))}_{\geq 0}\geq 1 >0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you would like to know how to "see" without using derivatives

$$x<y \Rightarrow 2x+\sin x < 2y + \cos y$$

To see this, you may use the fact that $|\sin t| < t$ for $t>0$.

To show is 
$$\sin x - \sin y < 2(y-x) \text{ for } x<y $$

or equivalently using $\sin x -\sin y = 2\sin \frac{x-y}{2} \cos \frac{x+y}{2}$

$$\sin \frac{x-y}{2} \cos \frac{x+y}{2}  <  y-x$$ $$\Leftrightarrow -\sin \frac{y-x}{2} \cos \frac{x+y}{2}   <  y-x \quad (\star)$$

So, for $\sin \frac{y-x}{2} \cos \frac{x+y}{2} \geq 0$ the inequality $(\star)$ is obviously satisfied since the RHS is always positive.

For  $\sin \frac{y-x}{2}\cos \frac{x+y}{2} < 0$ you have

$$ -\sin \frac{y-x}{2} \cos \frac{x+y}{2} = \left|  \sin \frac{y-x}{2}\right| \left| \cos \frac{x+y}{2}\right| \leq \left|  \sin \frac{y-x}{2}\right| < \frac{y-x}{2} < y-x$$

Answer (score 3):

$x<y\implies 2x+\sin x<2y+\sin y$,

because $f(x)=2x+\sin x$ is increasing,

because $f'(x)=2+\cos x>0$,

because $-1\le \cos x\le 1$.

Answer (score 1):

If you draw appropriate triangles in the unit circle, it's not hard to see that

$$|\sin\theta|\lt\theta\quad\text{and}\quad|1-\cos\theta|\lt\theta$$

for $0\lt\theta\lt\pi/2$, and from there it's not hard to argue that the inequalities hold for all $\theta\gt0$. (The absolute values are for convenience later on.)

Now let $y=x+\theta$ with $\theta\gt0$.  Then

$$\begin{align}
\sin x-\sin y&=\sin x-\sin(x+\theta)\\
&=\sin x-(\sin x\cos\theta+\cos x\sin\theta)\\
&=\sin x(1-\cos\theta)-\cos x\sin\theta\\
&\le|\sin x||1-\cos\theta|+|\cos x||\sin\theta|\\
&\lt1\cdot\theta+1\cdot\theta\\
&=2\theta\\
&=2(y-x)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Have you come across differentiation?  If so, notice that

$$ f'(x) = 2 + \cos x > 0 \quad \text{ for all } x$$

and it follows $f$ is strictly increasing.  A strictly monotonic function is necessarily one-to-one (injective).